# setConfirmCallback vs setReturnCallback

Tags: rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

why ***setReturnCallback*** executes before the ***setConfirmCallback*** ideally ***setConfirmCallback*** callback method should execute before the return callback.

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear what you are asking; if you mean the return callback is called before the confirm callback is called, that's simply the way the broker works.

It is important that it is executed that way. When you use `CorrelationData` we want to make sure the returned record is added to the `CorrelationData` before its `Future` is completed.